# The date filter doesn't work on Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, date, filter, sonata

I'm surprised I didn't find anything about the subject.

I'm using "Sonata Admin" with Symfony 3.3 and nothing happens when I try to filter a date...

[image]

The filter is not registered and it seems nothing happened on the page. 
I don't know why and I don't understand how to debug.

I extend my Admin class to personalize my fields and not to loose all when I generate again. Here's my code of the "child class" :

```
class CustomActionAdmin extends ActionAdmin {
/**
 * @param DatagridMapper $datagridMapper
 */
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    parent::configureDatagridFilters($datagridMapper);
    $datagridMapper->get('createdAt')->setOption('filter_type', 'doctrine_orm_date');
    $datagridMapper->get('createdAt')->setOption('field_type', 'date');
}
```

Nothing special, I think... ? 
Format in the table is : 27.09.2018 00:00:00 
and format in filter is "27 septembre 2018" but I think it shouldn't have any importance with the date type ?

Someone would have an idea... ?

Thank you !

Comment: First thing I would check is query generated from Sonata in Symfony toolbar, to see what query its generates.

Comment: I had to do something else, because there were other priorities, but I'll look at the query next time. Thank you very much for the advice.